# How do I have my calculator output a full expression after it calculates the answer?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I am creating a calculator for a C++ class and I am trying to output a full equation instead of just having the program spit out the answer. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to have it change per case. I experimented with an if statement, but that ended up not working out. Any criticism is appreciated to my code, but I am looking for a relatively easy solution so I can output a full equation instead of just an answer to create a more user friendly experience.

Here is my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//---------- Function Prototypes -----------
void print_menu();
double get_value();
double divide(double, double);
double subtraction(double, double);
double multiplication(double, double);
double SARCC(double, double);
double VolRCC(double, double);
double SARCCone(double, double);
void ShowProgramHeader();

//--------------  Main -------------------
int main() {
    ShowProgramHeader();
    double operand1, operand2, answer;
    int choice, valid_choice;
    do {
        print_menu();
        cin >> choice;
        valid_choice = 1;           // assume choice is valid
        switch (choice) {
        case 0:                    // program will exit
            break;
        case 1:                    // addition
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = operand1 + operand2;
            break;
        case 2:                    // division
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = divide(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        case 3: // subtraction
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = subtraction(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        case 4: // multiplication
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = multiplication(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        case 5: // SA right circular cylinder
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = SARCC(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        case 6: // Vol. right circular cylinder
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = VolRCC(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        case 7: // SA right circular cone
            operand1 = get_value();
            operand2 = get_value();
            answer = SARCCone(operand1, operand2);
            break;
        default:
            valid_choice = 0;   // choice is invalid
            cout << "Invalid Choice." << endl;  
        }
        if (valid_choice) {   // if choice is valid, print the answer
                cout << endl << "Answer= " << answer  <<  endl;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);    // if not 0, loop back to start
    return 0;
}

//--------------  Functions -------------------

//----------------- get_value function ----------------
double get_value() {
    double temp_value;
    cout << "Please, enter a value: ";
    cin >> temp_value;
    cout << "Thanks." << endl;
    return temp_value;
}
//-------------------- print_menu function -------------
void print_menu() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Add (1)" << endl;
    cout << "Divide (2)" << endl;
    cout << "Subtract (3)" << endl;
    cout << "Multiply (4)" << endl;
    cout << "Surface Area of Right Circular Cylinder (5)" << endl;
    cout << "Volume of Right Circular Cylinder (6)" << endl;
    cout << "Surface Area of Right Circular Cone (7)" << endl;
    cout << "Exit (0)" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
}
//---------- Show Program Header function ----------
void ShowProgramHeader() {
    cout << "Grant Dearing" << "\n" << "CS120-02" << "\n" << "Lab 6" << "\n" << "5 October 2018" << endl;
}
//----------- Subtraction Function --------------
double subtraction(double subtractor, double subtractee) {
    return (subtractee - subtractor);
}
//----------- Multiplication Function ---------
double multiplication(double multiplier1, double multiplier2) {
    return (multiplier1 * multiplier2);
}
//----------- Divison Function ---------
double divide(double dividend, double divisor) {
    if (divisor == 0) {
        return 0;  // avoids divide by zero errors
    }
    else 
        return (dividend / divisor);
    }
//---------- SA Right Circular Cylinder --------
double SARCC(double radius, double height) {
        return ((2 * M_PI*radius*height) + (2 * M_PI*pow(radius, 2)));
}
//--------- Vol Right Circular Cylinder --------
double VolRCC(double radius, double height) {
    return (M_PI*pow(radius, 2)*height);
}
//---------- SA Right Circular Cone --------
double SARCCone(double radius, double height) {
    return ((M_PI*radius)*(radius + (sqrt(pow(height, 2) + pow(radius, 2)))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For addition, try something like

```
   case 1:                    // addition
        operand1 = get_value();
        operand2 = get_value();
        answer = operand1 + operand2;
        cout << operand1 << " + " << operand2 << " = " << answer << endl;
        break;
```

Then just do the same for all of the other cases, and remove the `cout << endl << "Answer= " << answer  <<  endl;` line.

Comment: While it's a bit less readable, it does minimize code repetition: Add `cout << " = " << answer << endl;` and the end of the code, and then only put `cout << operand1 << " + " << operand2;` for the addition case. If you ever want write something without an equal sign, you'll have to go back to my original suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to solve this problem is to have a big `cout << var1 << ' + ' << var2 << ' = ' << answer << endl;`, for each kind of computation your calculator can do. That can get to be pretty long when you are doing the surface area of a cone or whatever, and there's the risk that the formula you say you are evaluating and the formula you are actually evaluating might not match, if you make a mistake.

The Right Way to handle this problem is probably to use an [expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) system. You would have a class (`ExpressionNode`) that represents an instance of an operation like addition, division, or raising-to-a-power, or just a literal number like 5 or Pi. That class would have a method to evaluate the expression it represents and return a `double`, evaluating the left and right arguments to the operation first if necessary. It would also have a method to *print* the expression it represents, either printing out the number if it is just a number, or printing the left argument, ' + ', and then the right argument, if it represents addition, and so on.

Then your different calculator functions would take in inputs and return not final computed values, but expression trees representing how to compute those values, and the main loop would print out the expression that computes the answer, and then evaluate it and print the result.

If you don't want to implement this all yourself, [the Boost library provides a "Proto" library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.getting_started) that gives you expression trees and ways to evaluate them, but its documentation assumes you know some things about how parsing expressions into expression trees works, what "terminals" are, and so on. But their tutorial has a calculator example.